# Speeding up large matrix subsetting and addition

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to speed up this subsetting and addition of large matrices containing numeric and NA values, which currently runs in a little under 2 seconds on my computer. I'm hoping to speed it up because I have to run it many thousands of times with different values.

Sample data:

```
set.seed(1)
ids = 1:500
row_ids_1 = sample(c(rep(0, 100000), sample(ids, 400000, replace = TRUE)))
row_ids_2 = sample(c(rep(0, 100000), sample(ids, 400000, replace = TRUE)))
row_ids_3 = sample(c(rep(0, 100000), sample(ids, 400000, replace = TRUE)))
row_ids_4 = sample(c(rep(0, 100000), sample(ids, 400000, replace = TRUE)))
row_ids_5 = sample(c(rep(0, 100000), sample(ids, 400000, replace = TRUE)))
row_ids_6 = sample(c(rep(0, 100000), sample(ids, 400000, replace = TRUE)))
matrix_1 = matrix(sample(1:100, length(ids)*20, replace = TRUE), nrow = length(ids), ncol = 20)
matrix_2 = matrix(sample(1:100, length(ids)*20, replace = TRUE), nrow = length(ids), ncol = 20)
```

Expression I'm hoping to speed up:

```
result <-
  matrix_1[match(row_ids_1, ids),] + 
  matrix_2[match(row_ids_2, ids),] + 
  matrix_2[match(row_ids_3, ids),] + 
  matrix_2[match(row_ids_4, ids),] + 
  matrix_2[match(row_ids_5, ids),] + 
  matrix_2[match(row_ids_6, ids),]
```

Comment: In your code as written, the only effect of the match calls is to replace 0's with NAs. Is this the intended effect? If so there's clearly faster ways to replace 0's with NAs than with a call to match.

Comment: I do want to replace the zeros with NAs but the match calls are doing more than that. They are looking up and ordering the rows to be added.